# Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled. - esp32 & PN532

Tags: nfc, arduino-esp32, pn532

I am trying to change the state of some motors using a PN532 sensor, I want that those motors vibrate with a determinate frequency so I am using a timer. Those motors turn off when contador=20 or when I press a bottom but when the motors turn off, I got a message error. How can I solve it?
This is my code.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h> //Librería para comunicación SPI serial parallel interface 
#include <UNIT_PN532.h> //Librería Modificada  ya que la tasa de bits que viene predefinida
//en la librería de Adafruit es demasiado rápida para el ESP32 por lo cual se debe modificar este dato para poder utilizarlo con esta placa

//Conexiones SPI del ESP32
#define PN532_SCK  (18)
#define PN532_MOSI (23)
#define PN532_SS   (5)
#define PN532_MISO (19)
#define motor1 (33)
#define motor2 (32)
#define motor3 (25)
#define motor4 (26)
#define boton1 (2)


void IRAM_ATTR onTimer();
void isr_boton();
uint8_t DatoRecibido[4]; //Para almacenar los datos
int contador=0;
int boton_restart=0;

UNIT_PN532 nfc(PN532_SS);// Línea enfocada para la comunicación por SPI

hw_timer_t * timer = NULL;


void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200); //Inicio de puerto Serial a 115200 baudios
  nfc.begin(); //Comienza la comunicación del PN532
  
  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();//Obtiene información de la placa

  if (! versiondata) { //Si no se encuentra comunicación con la placa --->
    Serial.print("No se encontró la placa PN53x");
    while (1); // Detener
  }

  //Establezca el número máximo de reintentos para leer de una tarjeta.
  //Esto evita que tengamos que esperar eternamente por una tarjeta,
  //que es el comportamiento predeterminado del PN532.
  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

  nfc.SAMConfig(); //Configura la placa para realizar la lectura

 // Serial.println("Esperando una tarjeta ISO14443A ...");
  pinMode(motor1, OUTPUT); // Se configuran los pines como salidas
  pinMode(motor2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(boton1, INPUT_PULLDOWN);
  attachInterrupt(boton1,isr_boton,RISING);
}

void loop() {
  boolean LeeTarjeta;//Variable para almacenar la detección de una tarjeta
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Búfer para almacenar el UID devuelto
  uint8_t LongitudUID; //Variable para almacenar la longitud del UID de la tarjeta

  //Recepción y detección de los datos de la tarjeta y almacenamiento en la variable "LeeTarjeta"
  LeeTarjeta = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &LongitudUID);
  
  Serial.println("loop");
  //Se detecto un tarjeta RFID
  if (LeeTarjeta) {
    
    timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true);  // timer 0, MWDT clock periodo = 12.5 ns * TIMGn_Tx_WDT_CLK_PRESCALE -> 12.5 ns * 80 -> 1000 ns = 1 us, countUp--> conteo ascendente
    timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &onTimer, true); // edge (not level) triggered 
    timerAlarmWrite(timer, 1000000, true); // 1000000 * 1 us = 1 s, autoreload true
    timerAlarmEnable(timer); // enable    
  }

  //Si no se detecta tarjeta
  else
  {
    Serial.print(PN532_SCK);
    Serial.println("Se agotó el tiempo de espera de una tarjeta");
  }
 
  vTaskDelay(portMAX_DELAY); // wait as much as posible ...
  
}
void IRAM_ATTR onTimer(){ // interrupción del timer cuando se c
  digitalWrite(motor1,!digitalRead(motor1)); // cambio de estado de los leds 
  digitalWrite(motor2,!digitalRead(motor2));
  digitalWrite(motor3,!digitalRead(motor3));
  digitalWrite(motor4,!digitalRead(motor4));
  contador++;
  //Serial.print(contador);
  
  if (contador==20||boton_restart==1){
    digitalWrite(motor1,LOW); // cambio de estado de los leds 
    digitalWrite(motor2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor4,LOW);
    contador=0;
    timerDetachInterrupt(timer); 
   
    nfc.startPassiveTargetIDDetection(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A);
    Serial.print("fin");
    //ESP.restart();
    
    }
}
void isr_boton(){
  boton_restart=1;
  
  }
```

and the complete message error

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400849c6  PS      : 0x00050831  A0      : 0x800d14cb  A1      : 0x3ffbf0a0  
A2      : 0x00000044  A3      : 0x00018044  A4      : 0x000637ff  A5      : 0x3ffbf080  
A6      : 0x000000ff  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x000000ff  A9      : 0x40089550  
A10     : 0x00000003  A11     : 0x00060c23  A12     : 0x80081abc  A13     : 0x3ffbf060  
A14     : 0x3ffbff40  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x0000001b  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x800d14d7  LBEG    : 0x400014fd  LEND    : 0x4000150d  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffe  
Core 1 was running in ISR context:
EPC1    : 0x400849c6  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x40083833

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Backtrace: 0x400849c6:0x3ffbf0a0 0x400d14c8:0x3ffbc6b0 0x400e1d5b:0x3ffbc6d0 0x400885ee:0x3ffbc6f0 0x40086e9d:0x3ffbc710

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:1044
load:0x40078000,len:10124
load:0x40080400,len:5856
entry 0x400806a8
```

I think the error is using *nfc.startPassiveTargetIDDetection(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A)* but I am not sure.

Comment: 1) download and install [EspExceptionDecoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder/blob/master/README.md) to decode the error trace. 2) your `boton_restart` need to be declared as `volatile`. 3) no where in your code the `boton_restart` get reset to `0` after it has been set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use IDE 2.x, java tools don't work any more.

Try using a different tool like https://github.com/holgerlembke/ESPEDfGK